# result of search() as character string

Tags: r

I'd need to present the result of the command `(.packages.())` in the form `"package-name","package-name","package-name"` with quotation marks and commas. I tried with `print` and `paste` ... but even after four hours I couldn't get the right result!

```
paste((.packages()),collapse=",")
```

almost works, but the quotation marks are only at the very first and the very last position. And `collapse="",""` doesn't work.
Can anybody help me?

Best

Comment: The collapse argument could have been either `"\",\""`, or `'","'`. You can use single-quotes on the "outside" if you want double-quote characters to be actually bona fide characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using `paste` twice:

```
paste0('"',paste((.packages()),collapse='","'),'"')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to what you had, except I use `sprintf('"%s"', .packages())` instead of `.packages()` to add quotes around package:

```
> paste(sprintf('"%s"', .packages()), collapse=",")
[1] "\"stats\",\"graphics\",\"grDevices\",\"utils\",\"datasets\",\"methods\",\"base\""
```

You might be thrown off by all the `\"` but that's how R `print`s a double-quote (it really is a single character, the double quote). Things will look as you expect if you pass them to `cat` or other functions for writing to files/filehandles:

```
> cat(paste(sprintf('"%s"', .packages()), collapse=","))
"stats","graphics","grDevices","utils","datasets","methods","base"
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat` and `paste` can do it.;

```
 cat("\"", paste0(  .packages()[1:15] , collapse="\", \""), "\"", sep="")
 #"stats4", "latticeExtra", "RColorBrewer", "lattice", "sp", "Formula", "cluster", "sos", "brew", "stats", "graphics", "grDevices", "utils", "datasets", "methods"
```

If you just look at the console output of the paste version you see why I used cat to tidy up the ends and make the display look less cryptic:

```
 paste0(  .packages()[1:15] , collapse="\", \"")
#[1] "stats4\", \"latticeExtra\", \"RColorBrewer\", \"lattice\", \"sp\", \"Formula\", \"cluster\", \"sos\", \"brew\", \"stats\", \"graphics\", \"grDevices\", \"utils\", \"datasets\", \"methods"
```

After going through this I realized it's not much different than agstudy's contribution, but the `cat` function does allow you to more completely control what gets displayed. The downside of `cat` is that you cannot assign the output to an object. If you did this there would not be a value in `res`:

```
res <- cat("\"", paste0(  .packages()[1:15] , collapse="\", \""), "\"")
res
# NULL
```